# Creating a podcasting app android - use MediaPlayer class to play the podcast?

Tags: android, mp3, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager, podcast

So I am creating a podcasting app and I was wondering if playing a podcast such as this http://www.npr.org/rss/podcast.php?id=122287224 - will MediaPlayer work to play such a podcast? I have never used MediaPlayer and I am just wondering if that would work.

Comment: It should work. I have not build something like this myself, but have seen a few examples that would suggest that it'll work.

Comment: Could you please help me with some sources to podcast API? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yea you can , just parsing the xml and get the link of the xml and using the media player in streaming the mp3

this tutorial help you

here how to parse xml

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

media player and streaming 
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-i

http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/

http://blog.endpoint.com/2011/03/api-gaps-android-mediaplayer-example.html

http://androidstreamingtut.blogspot.com/2012/08/custom-progressive-audio-streaming-with.html

Comment: Thank you. These are pretty useful links.